# Java Swing Timer Not Clear

Tags: java, swing, timer, sleep

I have been having some problems with using the Timer function of Java swing. I am fairly new to programming with Java, so any help is greatly appreciated. I have looked over many other Timer questions on this site but none of them have answered my question. I have made a GUI that allows you to play rock paper scissors, where you can choose from clicking three buttons. I want my program to sleep for around 1 second after you click the button, and again after it displays a message. After I realized Thread.sleep() wouldn't work for my GUI, I tried to implement a timer.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.io.*;

public class rps { 
//ROCK PAPER SCISSORS
static JLabel middle = new JLabel();
static JLabel them = new JLabel();
static JLabel yourWins = new JLabel();
static JLabel theirWins = new JLabel();
static JPanel yourPanel = new JPanel();
static JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
static JLabel blank1 = new JLabel();
static JLabel blank2 = new JLabel();
static JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");
static JButton paper = new JButton("Paper");
static JButton scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
static int yw = 0;
static int tw = 0;
static ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler();

public static void main(String[] args) { 

    //Create the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rock Paper Scissors");
    frame.setSize(500, 500); //Setting the size of the frame

    middle.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30)); 
    middle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    them.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    them.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    yourWins.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    theirWins.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    //Creating panels
    JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel();

    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1); 
    Border wlb = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1); 
    them.setBorder(border);
    yourPanel.setBorder(border);
    bigPanel.setBorder(border);
    yourWins.setBorder(wlb);
    theirWins.setBorder(wlb);
    middlePanel.setBorder(border);

    //Creating grid layouts 
    GridLayout yourGrid = new GridLayout(1,3,10,10); 
    GridLayout theirGrid = new GridLayout(1,1); //One row, one column
    GridLayout middleGrid = new GridLayout(5,1);
    GridLayout bigGrid = new GridLayout(3,1);//Two rows, one column

    //Setting the layouts of each panel to the grid layouts created above
    yourPanel.setLayout(yourGrid); //Adding layout to buttons panel
    them.setLayout(theirGrid); //Adding layout to label panel
    middlePanel.setLayout(middleGrid); 
    bigPanel.setLayout(bigGrid);

    //Adding r/p/s to your grid.
    yourPanel.add(rock);
    yourPanel.add(paper);
    yourPanel.add(scissors);

    //Adding w/l rations to middlegrid.
    middlePanel.add(theirWins);
    middlePanel.add(blank1);
    middlePanel.add(middle);
    middlePanel.add(blank2);
    middlePanel.add(yourWins);

    //Attaching the listener to all the buttons
    rock.addActionListener(listener);
    paper.addActionListener(listener);
    scissors.addActionListener(listener);

    bigPanel.add(them);
    bigPanel.add(middlePanel);
    bigPanel.add(yourPanel); 

    //Shows the score at 0-0.
    yourWins.setText("Your wins: " + yw);
    theirWins.setText("Their wins: " + tw);

    frame.getContentPane().add(bigPanel); //panel to frame 
    frame.setVisible(true); // Shows frame on screen
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

//Class represents what do when a button is pressed
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);

        String tc = random();
        them.setText("They chose: " + tc + "!");
        if (e.getSource() == rock) {
            whoWins("rock", tc);
        } else if (e.getSource() == paper) {
            whoWins("paper", tc);
        } else if (e.getSource() == scissors) {
            whoWins("scissors", tc);
        }
        yourWins.setText("Your wins: " + yw);
        theirWins.setText("Their wins: " + tw);

        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
} 

public static String random() {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    if (random == 0) {
        return "Rock";
    } else if (random == 1) {
        return "Paper";
    } else if (random == 2) {
        return "Scissors";
    }
    return "";
}

public static void whoWins(String yc, String tc) {
    if (yc.equals("rock")) {
        if (tc.equals("Rock")) {
            middle.setText("It's a tie!");            
        } else if (tc.equals("Paper")) {
            middle.setText("You lose!");
            tw++;
        } else if (tc.equals("Scissors")) {
            middle.setText("You win!");
            yw++;
        }
    } else if (yc.equals("paper")) {
        if (tc.equals("Rock")) {
            middle.setText("You win!");
            yw++;
        } else if (tc.equals("Paper")) {
            middle.setText("It's a tie!");
        } else if (tc.equals("Scissors")) {
            middle.setText("You lose!");
            tw++;
        }
    } else if (yc.equals("scissors")) {
        if (tc.equals("Rock")) {
            middle.setText("You lose!");
            tw++;
        } else if (tc.equals("Paper")) {
            middle.setText("You win!");
            yw++;
        } else if (tc.equals("Scissors")) {
            middle.setText("It's a tie!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

What is actually happening is there is no delay from when I press the button to a message displaying, because clearly I am not using the timer correctly. I would like the timer to just run once, and after it runs the code will execute. However, when I click a button the timer will run on repeat although setRepeats is false. Therefore, the message I want to display, instead of being delayed, is displayed instantaneously but then goes on a loop and keeps displaying a message (the message is random) until I shut off the program. If I click the button again, it will double the tempo of the timer it seems, and the messages display twice as fast and so on and so forth.

```
them.setText("They chose: " + tc + "!");
```

This is the message that is displayed on repeat, with the variable tc changing every time. The timer seems to just be displaying this message every timer interval (1s).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

So I added this section :

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        // I'd be disabling the buttons here to prevent
        // the user from trying to trigger another 
        // update...

        // This is an instance field which is used by your
        // listener

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, listenert);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
}
private static class timer implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String tc = random(); //A method that chooses a random word.
        them.setText("They chose: " + tc + "!"); 
        if (e.getSource() == rock) {
            whoWins("rock", tc); //whoWins is a method that will display a message.
        } else if (e.getSource() == paper) {
            whoWins("paper", tc);
        } else if (e.getSource() == scissors) {
            whoWins("scissors", tc);
        }
        yourWins.setText("Your wins: " + yw);
        theirWins.setText("Their wins: " + tw);

        // Start another Timer here that waits 1 second
        // and re-enables the other buttons...
    }
}
```

so what I believe happens now is when I click a button, the buttonhandler listener starts the timer which is attached to the timer listener (named listenert) which will run the code in the actionPerformed of the timer class. however the sleep function still is not working

EDIT 2.5:

```
 private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        final JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String tc = random();
                        them.setText("They chose: " + tc + "!");
                        if (button == rock) {
                            whoWins("rock", tc);
                        } else if (button == paper) {
                            whoWins("paper", tc);
                        } else if (button == scissors) {
                            whoWins("scissors", tc);
                        }
                        yourWins.setText("Your wins: " + yw);
                        theirWins.setText("Their wins: " + tw);
                    }
                });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();     

    }
}
```

that is what I have so far, I just need to add antoher sleep after 
    them.setText("They chose: " + tc + "!");
where would I put a timer.restart() if any? the timer.start() is at the end of the method which I don't quite understand.

Comment: You see how in MadProgrammer's `TestPane` example he create's an annonymous class `ActionListener` to pass as the argument to the `Timer`. Consider _that_, as your timer listener should not be the same as the `ButtonListener` (which is for the buttons). Combine that idea with the rest of his answer, and try to work it out. The point is not to give you the complete answer, but to have you learn how the timer should work :-)

Comment: You don't need the extra listener. Just do `new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {  ... });`. Try and work that. If you get stuck, post another edit of your attempt :-)

Comment: Inside those brackets am I supposed to insert what happens when the button is pressed or do a timer operation of some sort?

Comment: Not completely sure the result you're expecting, but yeah, but you also need an `actionPerformed`. The point of the ActionListener passed to the Timer is to do what you want performed after the delay. So what ever you want performed after the delay, that's what should go in the timer listener

Comment: Okay so I've made an edit, I think i've made progress thanks to you two. It now properly performs the delay and then displays the message, but this time does not set the middle text after the delay and FIRST message.

Comment: your `e.getSource()` is referencing the `Timer`. You should get a reference to the JButton from the ButtonListener actionPerformed then check against _that_ button. `final JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource()`, before declaring the timer

Comment: Then check if `button ==`

Comment: what do you mean get a reference? i'm really sorry but I'm super new to programming with java, and by get a reference I assume you mean place that line of code inside the buttonlistener?

Comment: I mean in the timer code when you do `if (e.getSource() ==`, that `e.getSource()` is referencing the Timer object, not the button. The button comes from the `ActionEvent` passed to the `actionPerformed` of the `ButtonHandler`. Remember they are two different listeners with two different source objects, one being the buttons, and the other being the Time

Comment: Alright, just one last question before I leave you and your helpfulness to yourselves. If I wanted to add another delay right after the first message is printed, I wouldbe able to do some sort of timer.restart() thing right? do I need to turn repeats on and then do a restart?

Comment: I'd post another question, because for 1. The question is unrelated, and 2. I Have a feeling the answer to the question is a little more complex than I can answer in a comment :-)

Comment: Alright I'll post another one, thanks sooo much for your help  tonight it's really been getting me through these tuff times you feel ;) anyway I'll post anotherone, hopefully you'll be ther eto help out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073741/java-swing-restart-timer-after-operation
if you have time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the `ActionListener` you supply to the `Timer` is notified when the timer "ticks", so you `ButtonHandler` `actionPerformed` should look more like...

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    // I'd be disabling the buttons here to prevent
    // the user from trying to trigger another 
    // update...

    // This is an instance field which is used by your
    // listener
    choice = e.getSource();

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, listener);
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

And your `listener` should look more like

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    String tc = random(); //A method that chooses a random word.
    them.setText("They chose: " + tc + "!"); 
    if (choice == rock) {
        whoWins("rock", tc); //whoWins is a method that will display a message.
    } else if (choice == paper) {
        whoWins("paper", tc);
    } else if (choice == scissors) {
        whoWins("scissors", tc);
    }
    yourWins.setText("Your wins: " + yw);
    theirWins.setText("Their wins: " + tw);

    // Start another Timer here that waits 1 second
    // and re-enables the other buttons...
}
```

For example...

You may consider taking a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

**Updated**

Start with a simple example...
    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

```
    private JLabel label;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        label = new JLabel();
        add(label);
        tick();

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tick();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void tick() {

        label.setText(sdf.format(new Date()));

    }
}
```

This just calls the `tick` method every half second to update the time on the `JLabel`...

Comment: I'm a bit confused, am I supposed to create two methods called actionPerformed? Could you elaborate on what you mean by disabling the buttons to prevent the user from making another update? When the timer ticks, what exactly happens to the listener, I'm not quite clear on that. The listener used is the same listener that is attatched to the buttons on my GUI, is that a problem?

Comment: I've looked over that webpage many times but I can't seem to extract any helpful information from it. It doesn't tell me where to put the timer code for it to only run once before the message is displayed.

Comment: Basically, when the `Timer` "ticks", it calls the supplied `ActionListener`'s `actionPerformed` method, this is how you know the timer went off

Comment: So is the problem here that I'm calling the timer within the method that it calls? And I'm not clear about the listener thing. If you look at my full code could you maybe elaborate a bit more? I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Listener is a ButtonHandler, it's all in the code above. I'm really lost, I tried running the last program you just posted but had no idea how after importing everything, and so I fail to understand your example.

Comment: So I added another listener and another class to handle timer operations, it's up in the edit. Still no delay, could I have a hint to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

firstly import the following ;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent ;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener ;

import javax.swing.Timer ;
```

then initialize the timer at the end of the form like this ;
public static void main(String args[]) {

```
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {        
            public void run() {       
            new mainprogramme().setVisible(true);    
        }
```

});

```
}    
    private Timer timer ;
```

then after initializing the timer add a public class like following;

public class progress implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

```
int n = 0 ;
if (n<100){
    n++ ;
    System.out.println(n) ;
}else{
    timer.stop() ;
}
}
}
```

after you do this go to the j Frame>right click and select>Events>window>window Opened and type the following ;

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        timer = new Timer(100,new progress()) ;
```

and after you do all this take a button name it as anything and type the following in its void like following ;

```
 timer.start();
```

AND THAT'S IT CODE IT AND THEN REPLY ME...