# Java Swing Restart Timer After Operation

Tags: java, swing, timer, sleep

I need my timer to restart or at least add another delay after a certain line of code is performed.

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        final JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String tc = random();
                        them.setText("They chose: " + tc + "!");

                        if (button == rock) {
                            whoWins("rock", tc);
                        } else if (button == paper) {
                            whoWins("paper", tc);
                        } else if (button == scissors) {
                            whoWins("scissors", tc);
                        }
                        yourWins.setText("Your wins: " + yw);
                        theirWins.setText("Their wins: " + tw);
                    }
                });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();     
    }
}
```

I would like to implement the second delay of the timer right after

```
them.setText("they chose: " + tc + "!");
```

yet I am not sure how to do this, am I supposed to restart the timer and if so where would I write that line of code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should delay immediately after the message is displayed (they chose:...) without needing user interaction. It's essentially supposed to be two delays broken up with a pause in between that's however long it takes to display the first message on screen.

Comment: Not needed anymore, thanks so much for all the help, I can finally develop my simple program beyond a sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to post this into your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072754/java-swing-timer-not-clear/23072847?noredirect=1#comment35261986_23072847), but it seems you've some progress, well done.

Okay, so, this example gives you three buttons to choose from.  When you click one, it records what you choose, disables the buttons and starts a `Timer` which waits 1 second.

The `Timer`'s `ActionListener` then checks to see what you choose and updates the output, then starts another `Timer` which waits 1 second, which then re-enables the buttons...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Chocies {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Chocies();
    }

    public Chocies() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton choice1;
        private JButton choice2;
        private JButton choice3;

        private JLabel output;

        private JButton choice;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            choice1 = new JButton("Door 1");
            choice2 = new JButton("Door 2");
            choice3 = new JButton("Door 3");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(choice1);
            panel.add(choice2);
            panel.add(choice3);

            output = new JLabel("Pick a door");
            output.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            add(output, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(panel);

            ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
            choice1.addActionListener(handler);
            choice2.addActionListener(handler);
            choice3.addActionListener(handler);
        }

        public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                output.setText("Wait for it...");
                choice = (JButton) e.getSource();
                choice1.setEnabled(false);
                choice2.setEnabled(false);
                choice3.setEnabled(false);
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerHandler());
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
            }

        }

        public class TimerHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (choice1 == choice) {
                    output.setText("Door 1 selected");
                } else if (choice2 == choice) {
                    output.setText("Door 2 selected");
                } else if (choice3 == choice) {
                    output.setText("Door 3 selected");
                }

                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        choice1.setEnabled(true);
                        choice2.setEnabled(true);
                        choice3.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Okay I've got it thanks to your answer, thanks so much! I just added another timer thing right after the first message is printed, and it works without a flaw. Thanks again so much for the time!

Comment: @user3534031 Sorry it took so long ;)