# How to lock button for 30 seconds if incorrect username/password 3 times?

Tags: java, forms, authentication

This is the code I have. It reads from a text file and compares it to the users input. I have been trying to add a counter++ and once count =3 do something but I just can't get it to work. I feel like it should be so easy....

```
boolean login = false;

while (read.nextLine() !=null) {
    String user = read.next();

    String pass = read.next();

    read.next();

    if(usernameT.getText().equals(user) && passwordT.getText().equals(pass)) {
        login = true;
        break;                 
    }
}

if (login) {
    new Menu();
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");

    usernameT.setText("");

    passwordT.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Well, that's [one possible way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073741/java-swing-restart-timer-after-operation/23073802#23073802)

Comment: I'd strongy recommend a visit to [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use a Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Cheers ik how to do the timer now. Just need to implement the count =3 now. Do I use an if statement or a for loop?

Comment: That would depend, do you want to break out of the `while` loop or raise some other condition within it

Answer (score -1):

Am I thinking along the write lines?

```
For(count=0;count<4){
if(login)
new Menu();
else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect 
username or password");
usernameT.setText("");
passwordT.setText("");
Count++
 }
}
```